# How can I write a function for an order Analysis that will take array of different object data types and return an object in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

Please, how would you get the average for quantity of the same date from the following data in kotlin.
A function to take this input and return an object with `{"Monday" : 3.40, "Tuesday": 4.5}` and a brief explanation how to pass the data into the function (because it doesn't have specific task) will be much appreciated.

````
        mapOf(
            "orderId" to 554,
            "creationDate" to "2017-03-25T10:35:20",
            "orderLines" to arrayOf(
                mapOf("productId" to 9872, "name" to "pencil", "quantity" to 3, "unitPrice" to 3.00)
            )
        ),
        mapOf(
            "orderId" to 555,
            "creationDate" to "2017-03-25T11:24:20",
            "orderLines" to arrayOf(
                mapOf("productId" to 9872, "name" to "Pencil", "quantity" to 1, "unitPrice" to 3.00),
                mapOf("productId" to 1746, "name" to "Eraser", "quantity" to 1, "unitPrice" to 1.00)
            )
        ),
        mapOf(
            "orderId" to 453,
            "creationDate" to "2017-03-27T14:53:12",
            "orderLines" to arrayOf(
                mapOf("productId" to 5723, "name" to "Pen", "quantity" to 4, "unitPrice" to 4.22),
                mapOf("productId" to 9872, "name" to "Pencil", "quantity" to 3, "unitPrice" to 3.12),
                mapOf("productId" to 3433, "name" to "Erasers Set", "quantity" to 1, "unitPrice" to 6.15)
            )
        ),
        mapOf(
            "orderId" to 690,
            "creationDate" to "2017-03-26T11:14:00",
            "orderLines" to arrayOf(
                mapOf("productId" to 9872, "name" to "pencil", "quantity" to 4, "unitPrice" to 3.12),
                mapOf("productId" to 4098, "name" to "Marker", "quantity" to 5, "unitPrice" to 4.50)
            )
        )```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Map`s containing a bunch of unrelated types is a bad idea, you're not supposed to do that in a statically typed language like Kotlin (and you lose a lot of the advantages of static typing if you do). Having an unstructured pile of `Any`s that you have to cast to the type you *think* it should be when you need to use it, that's asking for trouble.

You'd be better using classes instead, define your data:

```
data class OrderLine(
    val productId: Int,
    val name: String,
    val quantity: Int,
    val unitPrice: Float // *I don't recommend using floats for this*, see below
}

data class Order(
    val orderId: Int,
    val creationDate: String, // or you could parse it to a Date so you can work with it
    val orderLines: List<OrderLine>
)
```

Now you can create your data using a data structure instead of a random collection of stuff that may or may not contain valid data (there are no guarantees with a `Map<Any>`)

```
Order(
    orderId = 554, // you don't need the parameter names, just using them for comparison
    creationDate = "2017-03-25T11:24:20",
    orderLines = listOf(
        OrderLine(productId = 9872, name = "pencil", quantity = 3, unitPrice = 3.00f)
    )
)
```

And then you can easily do work on your data. You could add a function on your `Order` class that gives you the total item quantity for each order:

```
Order(...) {
    fun getTotalQuantity() = orderLines.sumOf(OrderLine::quantity)
    // or even better, as a property
    val totalQuantity: Int get() = orderLines.sumOf { it.quantity } // same as above
}

// use that to sum all the order totals
val total = orders.sumOf { it.totalQuantity }
```

or you could just run a function over the whole set of data

```
val total = orders.sumOf { order ->
    order.orderLines.sumOf { orderLine -> orderLine.quantity }
}
```

---

As for the price thing, you shouldn't use floats and doubles for monetary stuff - it's inaccurate and the errors can add up when you're working with a bunch of them. In your case, instead of having a unit price of `3.00`, I'd use an `Int` and call it 300 (cents or whatever). That way it's always exactly the right number, and you can divide by 100 for display purposes

Comment: (An alternative to `Int`, if your numbers don't all fit into an integral type or you prefer the clarity of keeping everything at the same scale, is `BigDecimal`. And see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for why floating-point values aren't a good fit.)

Comment: Wow, I never thought of data class. Data class made alot of sense. Thank you for this. I can work with this. Thanks alot,